# JSON Stringify like Web on Dart

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart, stringify

I have the next **Map**

```
Map<String, dynamic> example = {
  'isActive': true,
  'age': 24,
  'name': 'Sam',
  'childrens': ['Jhon', 'Elisa']
};
```

And i need to **Stringify** like the **JSON.stringify()** on **web**, to have a result like that

```
"{\"isActive\":true,\"age\":24,\"name\":\"Sam\",\"childrens\":[\"Jhon\",\"Elisa\"]}"
```

Actually using the **json.encode()** the result its the next and obviously its not equal to the above

```
{"isActive":true,"age":24,"name":"Sam","childrens":["Jhon","Elisa"]}
```

I need stringify my **Map** to **POST** in a **REST API**, if the **Stringify** its not equal to the web, the web can not read that.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is a `"` in the beginning and the end, as well as a `\` before each `"`.

You can imagine a simple function that does this conversion :

```
String stringify(String json) => '"${json.replaceAll('"', '\\"')}"';
```

Answer (score 0):

as the previous answer. Using the same function of @MickaelHrndz

```
String stringify(String json) => '"${json.replaceAll('"', '\\"')}"';
```

when using it. as your map variable "example" you need to encode it first before stringifying

Use the following => `stringify(json.encode(example))` . It will give you the correct format but don't forget to import this one `import 'dart:convert';` to use the encode function which I mentioned before

Good luck for you ^_^

**Update ------>** You can simply encode twice `json.encode(json.encode(example));`